# How to get <pre> like behaviour, but ignore <br>

Tags: html, css

I have made my own custom little blog and well, I realized it was ignoring whitespace within code tags. Well, the generated code is like

```
<div class="codebody">
Mycode<br/>
  other indented code<br/>
othercode<br/>
</div>
```

my codebody class looks like

```
.codebody {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Courier new, courier, mono;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #006600;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
```

Well, how can I make it so that indentation will show up in code tags, but it won't  add double-line breaks because of the `<br/>\n`?

Comment: nothing wrong with your code!!!

Comment: @jjj what? And it generates double spaced lines.

Comment: You should put quotation marks around font names containing spaces, like "Courier New": http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just figured out something.. I'm not sure that it works in all browsers, as it is a pretty nasty hack, but this is what I did

```
.codebody {
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Courier new, courier, mono;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #006600;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}

.codebody br{
    display: none;
}
```